# how to animate 2D curve arrows between two nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2, shapes, java-2d

I'm dealing with SVGPaths ( extends from Shape class ) in my project, moreover I'm trying to improve myself about animations in JavaFX. The thing is, I want to create 2D curved arrow animations between two nodes. Here you can see a sample of my map includes countries (in other words nodes/shapes) for being more clear to you.

[image: map]

So, consider that whenever a mouse cursor is over a node 2d arrowes will start animate to point neighbour countries. And, arrow will look something like this;

[image: arrow]

I researched internet and read some tutorials about animation in JavaFX but couldn't find something clear. I will appreciate for every answer and thanks anyway.

EDIT: Finally I implemented a proper animation about rotating an arrow between midpoints of two rectangles. Here is the simple source code ;

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(71, 64, 31, 21); // Create first rectangle
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(158, 64, 35, 21); // Create second rectangle

rect1.setVisible(false);
rect2.setVisible(false);

worldMap.getChildren().add(rect1); // add both of them in to the Group Layout
worldMap.getChildren().add(rect2);

Path path = new Path(); // Create the oath object which arrow will rotate on

MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();

moveTo.setX( rect1.getX()+ (rect1.getWidth()/2) );
moveTo.setY( rect1.getY()+ (rect1.getHeight()/2) );

QuadCurveTo quadCurveTo = new QuadCurveTo(); 

quadCurveTo.setX( rect2.getX()+(rect2.getWidth()/2) );
quadCurveTo.setY( rect2.getY()+(rect2.getHeight()/2) );
quadCurveTo.setControlX( ( rect1.getX()+rect2.getX() ) /2 );
quadCurveTo.setControlY( ( rect1.getY()-50) );

path.getElements().add(moveTo);
path.getElements().add(quadCurveTo);
path.setStrokeWidth(3); 
path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
path.setMouseTransparent(true);

final Polygon arrow = new Polygon(); // Create arrow

arrow.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {50.0,50.0,70.0,50.0,70.0,42.0,82.0,54.0,70.0,66.0,70.0,58.0,50.0,58.0});
arrow.setFill(Color.GREEN);

PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition(); //

pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(750));
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.setNode(arrow);
pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
pathTransition.play();
```

Now I want to create an animation which provides that arrow will start to extend from start point until it reaches to the end point.

Comment: Please don't mistake my comment as trolling - what made you decide to use JavaFX for this project? I've heard very little about it following the announcement at JavaOne back in '08 (was it '09?). Are you doing web stuff or a set-top (Java TV) project?

Comment: nope. Actually i'm implementing a board game which we called "Risk" maybe you've heard about it. And i started to implement the user interface part before starting the artificial intelligence part. Well, i'm using a SVG file for implement the world map which parsed from a .fxml file. So .fxml and svg files are the reason why i started to coding this game in JavaFX.

Comment: JavaFX can natively display animated gifs (such as in your question post) - `ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("http://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtz0.gif"));`, or are you perhaps asking for something different using the [JavaFX animation framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html)?

Comment: I've obseved a list of available animations in JFX, and seems, you will have to change your idea =) I would suggest to create a moving arrow. Arrow starts from the beginnig, and finishes in the end. again and again. It will be a path transition. May be several arrows along the line... Or an arrow, jumping from the beginning to the end.. -  It work so : create an animation, and make node visible, only when mouse is over.

Comment: @jewelsea Basically, i considered that method but i decided it will look maybe a little bit amateur :D. and also the angles will differ from node to node. Is there a way to resize (play on angles) this .gif file ?

Comment: @AlexanderKirov It doesnt have to have just only one arrow so your suggestion looks like very convincing,so i guess i have to draw paths from every node to each node right ? and then i can implement simple animations on them ?

Comment: Did you see, how attack order is animated in Civilization 5? It could be appropriate and doable in JFX

Comment: nope i havent seen it. well at least i should install then :)

Comment: You can use a [PerspectiveTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html) to resize (play on angles) for the .gif, but it might "look a little amateur" ;-)

Comment: Actullay i made it with using `PathTransition` class. I created an arrow from `Polygon`. and put that arrow on a path. So it rotates from start position to end position. The thing i wanna do is arrow will enable to extend from start position until it reaches to the end. :D

Comment: @jewelsea hey jewelsea i copied a source code of my animation you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX 2D/3D is very use the JDK 8.

Read example in [FXexperience](http://fxexperience.com/2013/02/javafx-3d-early-access-available/)

The download JKD 8 includes 3D.

[Download JDK8 http://jdk8.java.net](http://jdk8.java.net)

Comment: Sadly the full JDK 8 release won't be until 2014 (it was postponed until 6 months after the initial September 2013 date)